# Symfony swiftmailer delivery confirmation

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'd like to send emails with swiftmailer and I need confirmation of sent email and delivered. 
By default swiftmailer saves emails in cache and sends them in background to prevent waiting user for sending emails.

How can I achieve confirmation of sent emails?

Comment: Yes please... I would need to know that also

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to get 100% certainty. A mail can fail to be delivered for many reasons which has nothing to do with your application. A few suggestions though:

1) You can send all mails in BCC to another address. You can do this by combining `delivery_addresses` and `delivery_whitelist` configuration parameters https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#delivery-whitelist

2) You can use a specific mail server under your control, so you can check its queue / logs to see which mails have been actually delivered.

3) You can set a "Read receipt" to all outbound emails.